# How to get tomcat 5.5 to shut down from netbeans

Tags: netbeans, tomcat5.5

I have to run tomcat 5.5 with netbeans 6.7. This is NOT my choice. I have some legacy software that I am not allowed to re-write and must be supported.  The question is how do i get tomcat 5.5 to shut down properly using netbeans commands to shut it down?  It starts up fine with a bat file I created, but when I try to stop it, netbeans tries to shut it down for about 2 minutes then gives me a failure message, and I have to then have to stop it by ending the process.

The bat file is pretty simple.

```
set CATALINA_HOME=%cd%
tomcat5.exe
```

And could be my problem, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

can you show the bat file writte for getting tomcat started. There must be some problem with it.

Comment: Wish I could, if I worked at that place anymore, lol... thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans 6.x allows you to control an existing server. Simply go to the "Services" tab, right-click "Servers", and point it at your Tomcat installation. You may have issues if the Tomcat server is owned by a different user, but you can set up per-user configurations.

Alternatively, NetBeans 5.5 comes with a Tomcat 5.5 server.

Comment: Yes, that all works fine, but what i can get it to do is shut down from netbeans.  If I press the stop button, it just doesn't shut it down.  I end up going into the task manager and ending the process.